# How to print submitted form values?

Tags: php, html

why i cant view what i fill up in my html form. is that something wrong with my code in php code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>What's your name?</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>What's your name?</h1> 
        <h3>Writing a form for user input</h3>
        <form method = "post" action = "User.php"> 
            Please type your name:
            <input type = "text" name = "userName" value = " "><br> 
            <input type = "submit">  
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hi User</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hi User</h1> 
        <h3>PHP program that receives a value from "whatsName"</h3>  

    <?  
    print("<h3>Hi there , $userName </h3>");  
    ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider reading the php manual regarding [$_POST variabe](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Please format it correctly

Comment: @Harry variables in double-qoutes will be parsed!

Comment: you are correct @donald123

Comment: I think that you are using an old tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have Register Globals on (which you shouldn't so turn it off if so), the form variables won't automatically be expanded, so you need to pick them up from the `$_POST` array:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    print("<h3>Hi there , " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['userName']) . "</h3>");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have been used to badly configured servers running with `register_globals` turned on.

Or maybe you have moved to a version of PHP where `register_globals` has been removed i.e. PHP5.4 or greater.

You should address any data coming from a HTML `<form>` using the proper

```
$_POST['variableName']
```

or

```
$_GET['variableName']
```

With that in mind your code might look like this

```
print('<h3>Hi there , ' . $_POST['userName'] .  '</h3>');
```

Note: You should really be sanity checking the values passed in this type of data, and also checking if it is actually there. Although you should have been doing that anyway even if `register_globals` was turned on.